# How to get values from column C where corresponding column A value has different values in column B in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

[image]

I have a table layout like this.

For example, ip adress `62.133.172.128` is being used by more than one supplier.

I want to get all `auction_id` where one ip address was used by more than one supplier.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get all auction_id where one ip address was used by more than one supplier.

we can restate the above as: _get the auction_id if for each auction & ip combo, the number of distinct suppliers exceeds 1_

```
SELECT DISTINCT auction_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY auction_id, ip
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT supplier_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using `having` clause

```
select distinct(auction_id)
from tables
where ip in (
    select ip
    from tables
    group by ip
    having count(distinct(supplier_id)) > 1
)
```

**Edit**:

1. No need count in subquery

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. Putting a column name between parentheses does not change anything

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the script above doesn't work as expected, it gives auctions where different suppliers have different ip adressed, not the same

Comment: sorry for the wrong subquery, I didn't test it. Have edited it to only get the ip.

Comment: @kulan can you give some example data and expected result? Maybe I got your question wrong, but when I tried it with the data above it returns `7244` only